# I am facing laravel 5 routing

Tags: php, laravel-5

Its my route

```
Route::post('stoeBulkDealer', ['uses' => 'uploadDealerInfoController@stoeBulkDealer', 'as' => 'stoeBulkDealer']);
```

When i type in browser

http://localhost/bikeTest/public/stoeBulkDealer

then it shows the error MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

I don't want to show this error.I want to redirect it error page when any one type this

Comment: If you simply access that URL in the browser, you are doing a GET request, but your route maps to POST. In a production enviroment you can turn off errors in app config.

Comment: It helps to format your code in your post.

Comment: I want to redirect the url if any one try to direct this path

Answer (score 0):

Change route method **Post to get**

```
Route::get('stoeBulkDealer', ['uses' => 'uploadDealerInfoController@stoeBulkDealer', 'as' => 'stoeBulkDealer']);
```